# FaceTime added to Dock on Start Up

Tags: dock, facetime

I've encountered an interesting issue, and I am wondering if anyone else has experience with it.

Every time I restart my Mac, FaceTime is added back to the Dock. If I remove it from the Dock, it disappears. Restart, and it's back. I can remove other things just fine and they stay where they are, if I re-arrange FaceTime in the Dock it stays in its new position. Only when I remove it does something put it back.

Recent System Changes that *might* be causing it:

- EFI Update was just installed, it seemed to start happening as soon as it rebooted from installing this.
- XCode was upgrade from 4.0.1 to 4.0.2

Things I've tried:

- Deleting the ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist and rebuilt my Dock from scratch. After restarting, everything was exactly where I wanted it except the FaceTime app was added back.

(Anything else I try, I will edit and post here)

Has anyone else had problems with applications getting "stuck" in the Dock? How'd you fix it? FaceTime is neat, and I use it occasionally, but it isn't worth a dedicated spot on the Dock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove them from your dock, then go under the go tab in finder to your hard drive, then to library, and then in the prefences folder find `com.apple.dockfixup.plist` and move it to the recycle bin. Problem solved. This worked for me and I am running Lion so, hopefully it will work for you...

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused if your machine is managed -- more accurately, if your machine connected to an open directory server. Or perhaps to a OS X lion server, managing your machine's preferences.

Comment: It can even be managed locally by a policy file - stranger things have happened ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Open Activity Monitor, kill the "apsd-ft" process, remove FaceTime and then install it again.

There's also another solution I found on google (link [here](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/988516-facetime-icon-reappearing-on-dock/)):

> I was able to finally fix the problem by using the option in Onyx for LaunchServices rebuild. No more Facetime icon on reboot.

Comment: That did not resolve my issue. Removing FaceTime altogether and restarting resulted in a "?" appearing in the Dock, and rebuilding LaunchServices did not do the trick either. The application isn't running when I boot, it's just been "Kept" in the Dock.

Comment: This is very odd indeed. Sorry I couldn't help you.

Comment: My issue was similar to this. Thanks for the push in the right direction.